# MVC + controller view not displaying

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ajax for posting 2 values to my controller, the controller got the values but wouldn't display the view. Please assist what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

**Javascript:**

```
function grantPermission() {
        window.FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                accesstoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                var postData = { facebookUID: uid, facebookAccessTok: accesstoken };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SavePhoto")',
                    data: postData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // process the results from the controller action
                        //  window.location.href = response.Url;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                alert('User cancelled login');
            }
        }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
    };
```

**Button:**

```
   <input type="button" id="auth-loginlink" value="Proceed" onclick="grantPermission();"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
public PartialViewResult SavePhoto(string facebookUID, string facebookAccessTok)
        {
            return PartialView("BlurredPhoto");
        }
```

Comment: What is in the `response` data? You are trying to get the `Url` from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the returned HTML back into your document somewhere. e.g. If you add a

```
<div id='MyDiv'>
```

then change your ajax call to

```
            success: function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("#MyDiv").html(responseText);
            }
```

As Slaks has mentioned, you also need to change your [return datatype accepts to 'html'](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the HTML source from the server in your `success` callback.

You should probably start by not telling jQuery that the HTML is `datatype: 'json'`.